# Qt 5.7 QSqlError driverText() returns localized message

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

I'm using QSqlDatabase to connect to a sqlite3 database.

However when i use lastError() on a QSqlQuery, the QSqlError driverText() sometimes comes localized to my language (in this case pt_PT) however I would rather prefer the errors in English.

I cant seem to find anything in the docs of any of the above classes, nor google was much help I'm afraid.

Example:

```
qDebug() << "error" << q.lastError();
```

prints:

```
error QSqlError("", "Incorrespondência de contagem de parâmetros", "")
```

(This is a param number mismatch btw).

However doing a query on closed db

```
QSqlQuery q;
q.exec();
```

prints

```
error QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's just that string which didn't get a pt_PT translation?

Comment: @peppe, maybe yes, in any case the point still stands. I want the en_US strings not the pt_PT ones.

Comment: Apparently those strings always get translated (see for instance [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp.html#335)). I guess you can install a custom translator on QCoreApplication which checks if the translation context is a `QSQLiteResult` and then doesn't perform the translation.